# How can I get rid of the "back" button in my j2me programms while using LWUIT?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, midlet, lwuit-form

I'm writing a j2me application using LWUIT. I make a GUI in the LWUIT Resource Editor. But there's a little problem: when I switch through the `Forms` in my mobile application, the "back" soft button appears (it's task is to move user to the previous form). It turns out, however, that it's ineptly in my program. So, how can I get rid of it? If possible, how can I do so through a quite comfortable LWUIT Resource Editor (the whole GUI is made in it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Form` object have a method to capture the default back `Command`. This method is the following [Form API getBackCommand](http://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/Form.html#getBackCommand%28%29)

Use this method to get the back `Command`and after that, remove it with the Form.removeCommand(backCommand)

If this doesn't work, take a look in the `Commands` added in the resource editor. The resource editor always add a back `Command` when the `Form` is the navigation of the program